Jacobian of 2D element in 3D domain
I know how to calculate the Jacobian matrix for 2D elements in 2D and for 3D elements in 3D.
But for any 2D element(a quadrilateral element) which is embedded in 3D space, how do I calculate this Jacobian? If I use a traditional method for calculation, then my Jacobian matrix is a $2 \times 3$ matrix. Then how do I calculate its determinant?
PS: I am solving a finite element method where my physical space is in $(x,y,z)$ and isoparametric space is in $(\xi,n)$. For calculating the element stiffness matrices, I would need the determinant of the Jacobian but I could not figure out for this particular case.

I think that this is answered in a previous post.

I think the most general and elegant approach is to use a pseudo-inverse. The Jacobian, in general, is of size $n \times m$, where $n$ is the physical dimension of the domain/mesh, and $n$ is the dimension of the element basis\isoparametric space. For example, for a triangle in 3D structure $n=3$ and $m=2$. The Jacobian in this case is defined as:
$$
J = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{\xi}}& \frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{\eta}}\\ \frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{\xi}}& \frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{\eta}}\\ \frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{\xi}}& \frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{\eta}}\\\end{bmatrix}
$$
The determinant can be computed as:
$$
\mathrm{det}\;J = {(J^\top J)}^{\frac{1}{2}}
$$
If you also need the inverse Jacobian, you calculate it using the pseudo-inverse (of size $2 \times 3$) as:
$$
J^* = (J^\top J)^{-1} J^\top
$$
which is the matrix:
$$
J^* = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial{\xi}}{\partial{x}}& \frac{\partial{\xi}}{\partial{y}}& \frac{\partial{\xi}}{\partial{z}}\\ \frac{\partial{\eta}}{\partial{x}}& \frac{\partial{\eta}}{\partial{y}}& \frac{\partial{\eta}}{\partial{z}}\end{bmatrix}
$$

The Jacobian in 2D and 3D is respectively defined as
$$J^e=\begin{bmatrix}
      \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial\xi}&\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial\xi}\\
      \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial\eta}&\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial\eta}
      \end{bmatrix}$$
and
$$J^e=\begin{bmatrix}
      \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial\xi}
      &\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial\xi}
      &\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial\xi}\\
      \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial\eta}
      &\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial\eta}
      &\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial\eta}
      \end{bmatrix}$$
Consider each row of these matrices as vectors
$$a=\begin{pmatrix}
    \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial\xi}\\
    \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial\xi}
    \end{pmatrix}
~~~~\mathrm{and}~~~~
  b=\begin{pmatrix}
    \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial\eta}\\
    \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial\eta}
    \end{pmatrix}$$
or respectively
$$a=\begin{pmatrix}
    \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial\xi}\\
    \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial\xi}\\
    \dfrac{\partial z}{\partial\xi}
    \end{pmatrix}
~~~~\mathrm{and}~~~~
  b=\begin{pmatrix}
    \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial\eta}\\
    \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial\eta}\\
    \dfrac{\partial z}{\partial\eta}
    \end{pmatrix}$$
In either case the area scaling in the element is defined as
$\left\lVert a\times b\right\rVert$
It just turns out that in 2D $\left\lVert a\times b\right\rVert$ and $\left|J^e\right|$ are equivalent, but in 3D you can just use the original general definition for the area scaling and calculate it e.g. as
$\left\lVert a\times b\right\rVert
=\sqrt{\left\lVert a\right\rVert^2
       \left\lVert b\right\rVert^2-
       \left(a\cdot b\right)^2}$
